# Find amount of numbers that can sum to a number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I'm wondering if there is a formula to determine the total amount of numbers which can add to another number. Example: What combination of $4$ numbers adds to $4$. The answer is $1 + 1 + 1 + 1$. So there is only one solution. Of course this grows considerably as numbers get bigger. For a practical test is there a way to calculate the total solutions for $4$ numbers that add to $25$. If there is how can this be adjusted for larger sets. Like $20$ numbers that add to $113$.

Comment: Do you mean integers?  Positive integers?  We can always find an infinite number of fractions or irrational numbers that add to a given number if we like.

Comment: Good point @Mnifldz. Yes I mean positive integers.

Comment: There is a technique called "stars and bars", which can be applied almost immediately to your technique.  If you're looking for four positive integers that sum up to (say) $25$, then you are equivalently looking for four non-negative integers that sum up to $21$.  (One simply adds $1$ to each of these four non-negative integers to obtain the positive integers that sum up to $25$.)  From there, it is a simple formula for the proper binomial coefficient $\binom{24}{3} = \frac{24!}{3!21!}$, where $n! = n \times (n-1) \times (n-2) \times \cdots \times 2 \times 1$ is read "$n$ factorial".

Comment: (cont'd) Oops, I realized that this assumes you care about the order of the numbers.  If you don't, you want the number of partitions, which is different.  So: Is $2+1+1+1 = 5$ different from $1+1+1+2 = 5$, or is it the same?

Comment: Thanks for the info @BrianTung. I'm going to read up on "stars and bars".

Comment: If you don't care about the order of the numbers, then the count is the number of partitions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29